# Android basic API v2 MapActivity outOfMemory with 10 markers

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to implement map using Android Maps API v2 with Android Support Library, testing on Droid2 with Android 2.2
Everything is working well but just for a short period of time. Once I add 10 markers and try to move the map around or zoom in/out the following errors are thrown every second resulting in dreaded exception and crash follows.
I am doing nothing in the background. There is literally just the map and 10 markers.

Thank you for any tips.

Martin

**Errors:**

```
01-07 03:03:23.221: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12914): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 38714 objects / 1797752 bytes in 74ms
01-07 03:03:23.378: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(12914): 1048576-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-07 03:03:23.378: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(12914): VM won't let us allocate 1048576 bytes
01-07 03:03:23.378: WARN/System.err(12914): OutOfMemory
01-07 03:03:23.432: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12914): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8793 objects / 601896 bytes in 58ms
01-07 03:03:23.862: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(12914): 1048576-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-07 03:03:23.862: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(12914): VM won't let us allocate 1048576 bytes
01-07 03:03:23.870: WARN/System.err(12914): OutOfMemory
```

**Exception:**

```
01-07 02:45:12.432: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(12315): 1048576-byte external allocation too     large for this process.
01-07 02:45:12.432: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(12315): VM won't let us allocate 1048576 bytes
01-07 02:45:12.464: WARN/dalvikvm(12315): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400208b0)
01-07 02:45:12.479: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12315): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 18
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:498)
    at maps.r.h.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.cp.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.cp.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.cp.a.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.m.n.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.m.at.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.bq.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.w.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.w.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.w.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.ba.m(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.ba.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Layout:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      map:cameraTargetLat="49.85"
      map:cameraTargetLng="15.42"
      map:mapType="normal"
      map:uiCompass="true"
      map:uiRotateGestures="true"
      map:uiScrollGestures="true"
      map:uiTiltGestures="true"
      map:uiZoomControls="false"
      map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    />
```

**Markers:**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(49d, 16d))
            .draggable(true)
            .title("BUUUUU")
            .snippet("TEST"));
    }
```

Comment: It might because you are adding 10 markers only at a single position. Just try to add the marker on different positions.

Comment: thats just a testcase, behaves the same when markers are in different places (would have been a trivial google mistake if didnt)

Comment: I'm running the same issue on that device as well.  Granted I can draw 50 markers, but after 10 pans of the map it dies.  I was watching the heap and it never users all of the heap. I still had 5mb but it died when it asked for the same amount as your app.  Am I reading that 1048576-byte wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

How many size of marker image?
try to resize marker image smaller